# save a QWidget as an image

Tags: python, pyqt5, screenshot, qtablewidget

In pyqt5 i try:

```py
fileName = "qtable_widget.png"
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.parent_self.main_self.ui_scheduled_transmitions_create_window.review_table.size())
self.parent_self.main_self.ui_scheduled_transmitions_create_window.review_table.render(pixmap)
pixmap.save("qtable_widget.png", "PNG", -1)
```

But this captures only the view area of the QTableWidget. The QTableWidget has a vertical scrollbar.
Is there any way to capture all the qtablewidget?

Comment: use [`QWidget::grab`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab)?

Comment: what may i use as QRect?

Comment: @ChrisP As stated in the above linked docs, if no rect is supplied, the whole widget is included - which is what you want, right? Or are you saying you want to include the parts of the table hidden under the scrollbars as well? What exactly do you mean by "all" the table-widget?

Comment: If you want to capture the whole content area, you cannot just do that like this, because the view can only paint on what's visible from the viewport. The best solution would be to resize the table to include the proper content size, and then grab the full widget. To avoid any issues, you could use a temporary table view with the current model set, you don't even need to display it and you can destroy it afterwards. Obviously, if you have any delegate that alters the display in some way or style sheets that have effect on the view, you need to set them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scroll area is implemented in a way that only the *visible* contents are actually painted, and only when they are exposed within the viewport.

This means that you cannot simply call painting functions (which is what `render()` does) as you will always get the *visible* rectangle of the widget.

The solution is then to temporarily resize the table in order to expose all the contents.

My suggestion is to use a temporary table view, and set the same model on the original one.

The trick is to get the proper content area, which *includes* a rectangle starting from the viewport position and has a size based on the [`viewportSizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewportSizeHint). In order for this to work properly, the view should have both scroll bars disabled, so that you can get the proper size hint, then adjust the rectangle top left to the view origin point (`0, 0`), and add the right and bottom margins using the `frameWidth()`.

This is a simple example of the above:

```py
# just an example table
original = QTableWidget(100, 100)
for r in range(100):
    for c in range(100):
        original.setItem(r, c, QTableWidgetItem('{} {}'.format(r, c)))


temp = QTableView()
temp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
temp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
temp.setModel(original.model())

rect = QRect(temp.viewport().pos(), temp.viewportSizeHint())
rect.setTopLeft(QPoint())
margins = temp.contentsMargins()
temp.resize(rect.size() + QSize(margins.right(), margins.bottom()))

image = temp.grab()
image.save('qtable_widget.png')
temp.deleteLater()
```